# Wordpress how to get a single post link

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to go to `single.php` file when  this button is clicked.

```php
<div class="recepies-search">
        
        <div class="card m-1" style="width: 18rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="<?get_the_post_thumbnail()?>" >
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title"><?php the_title();?></h5>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="<?php get_permalink()?>">click</button>

  </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Do you have this code inside the query loop? At least you can set the post ID into function get_permalink: `get_permalink($post_id)`. Also by sure that before some functions you must have echo to print the result of the function - depends on which function you choose. Please read docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace this:

```php
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="<?php get_permalink()?>">click</button>
```

with this:

```php
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">click</a>
```

And then style your `a` tag like a button.